# sidecar with kubernetes provider for terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I have to add 2 containers as sidecars in a k8s deployment. I am using terraform Kubernetes provider. Is it available in terraform Kubernetes provider? If yes, any example would be helpful.

```
    resource "kubernetes_deployment" "test_deployment" {
      metadata {
        name = test_nginx
        namespace = test
        labels = {
          app = test_nginx
        }
      }
    
      spec {
        replicas = "2"
    
        selector {
          match_labels = {
            app = test_nginx
          }
        }
    
        template {
          metadata {
            labels = {
              app = test_nginx
            }
          }
          spec {
             container {
              image             = nginx
              name              = local_nginx
              .
              .
              .
              image             = logrotate
              name              = local_logrotate
              .
              .
              .
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

> Error: Attribute redefined │ │ On deployment\deployment.tf line 84: The argument "image" was already set │ at deployment\deployment.tf:28,11-16. Each argument may be set only once.

Comment: Sidecar containers are just additional containers, there is no special resource in the K8s provider. What have you tried already? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another `container` block:

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "test_deployment" {
  metadata {
    name = test_nginx
    namespace = test
    labels = {
      app = test_nginx
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = "2"

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = test_nginx
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = test_nginx
        }
      }
      spec {
         container {
          image             = nginx
          name              = local_nginx
          .
          .
          .
          }

         # new container block
         container {
          image             = logrotate
          name              = local_logrotate
          .
          .
          .
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would also suggest moving to a new version of deployments [1], i.e., `kubernetes_deployment_v1`.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/deployment_v1

Comment: Thanks, @Marko. It worked. I have also moved to v1 as per your suggestion.

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be much appreciated.